# Do Indexes need a Synonym to be used

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I noticed that indexes are still being used even if they don't have a Synonym to the Current Schema.
I ran the test below:

```
SHOW USER;

----------------
USER is "APPS"
```

Created table under a different Schema `HRCUST`

```
create table hrcust.test_idx_tbl
(
    id      number
,   data1   varchar2(100)
,   data2   varchar2(100)
);
```

Created a Synonym for the Custom Table

```
create synonym apps.test_idx_tbl for hrcust.test_idx_tbl;
```

Created an Index under the other schema:

```
create index hrcust.test_idx_idx on hrcust.test_idx_tbl(id);
```

inserted some dummy values:

```
begin

    for i in 1..10000 loop

        insert into hrcust.test_idx_tbl
        (
            id    
        ,   data1 
        ,   data2 
        )
        values
        (
            i
        ,   'data'||i
        ,   'data'||i
        );

    end loop;

end;
```

Checking the Explain plan, it still used the Index even if i explicitly used the `APPS` Synonym

```
select  *
from    apps.test_idx_tbl
where   id = 1;

Plan hash value: 3233418199

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |              |     1 |   117 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_IDX_TBL |     1 |   117 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TEST_IDX_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ID"=1)
```

So does this mean its unnecessary to create Synonyms on Indexes?
And will there be negative effects if we put Synonyms on Indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unnecessary (pointless but harmless) to create synonyms on indexes because there is no reason for anyone to reference the index name in their code. No one ever does.

Comment: You might reference an index directly in an access hint; but there's still no need for the synonym.